# Is it permitted to quote something with informal language, like an interview excerpt with 'haha', in a thesis?

Tags: thesis, writing, quotation

One of the interview excerpt I want to quote include "haha."

Is it permitted to quote an interview excerpt with 'haha' in a thesis?

I asked because it seems like it is too informal.

Comment: Where do you want to quote it?

Comment: Why would you think you *couldn't*?

Comment: Consider asking people you write the excerpt for.

Comment: I want to quote it in a thesis. I asked because it is too informal.

Comment: Direct quotes are _never_ informal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should consult with your advisor about conventions in your field.  I think generally, people lightly edit interviews such as these, so if the laughter isn't revelant to what the subject is saying, you can leave it out.  If it is important, you don't have to onomatopoetically transcribe it as "haha."  You can write 
"[laughter]" or "[interviewee laughs]."

Comment: There is a difference between laughing and *saying* "haha": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClynhFKMs3c.

Answer (score 0):

It is permitted to do whatever is necessary to get the information across.

Comment: @J.Zimmerman The question is whether something is permitted; my response is yes. How is it not an answer?

Comment: You might improve your response by addressing the issue of informality (it is not clear that the "haha" is necessary to get the information across).

Comment: @J.Zimmerman That's a question of whether it's *advisable*, not *permitted*.